# How to find the count of top customers contributing to 70% of revenue of each shop (hive/sql/python)

Tags: python, sql, hive

I am trying to find the number of customers  contributing to 70% revenue for each shop.

| shop_no | customer | % contri in revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0.1 |
| 1 | B | 0.5 |
| 1 | B | 0.4 |
| 2 | A | 0.2 |
| 2 | B | 0.5 |
| 2 | C | 0.3 |

As mentioned in the table, for shop 1,the answer should be 1 (customer B as he is contributing to 70% or more of revenue) and similarly for second shop the answer should be 2 (cust B,C are together contributing to 70% or more).

I tried creating a table with cumulative revenue percentage for each shop in descending order in table xxx and in the next table i thought I will count the number of customers till the cumulative percentage is 0.7 for each shop.

**create table xxx as select *, sum (perc_cust_rev) over (partition by shop_no order by perc_cust_rev desc) as cum_rev from abc;

create table xxx2 as select shop_no, sum(case when cum_rev <=0.7 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_70
from xxx group by shop_no;**

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And note that this problem falls into the class of np-complete problems.

Comment: @Strawberry is there a way to make it simple? I just need the final count of customers contributing to 70% of revenue for each shop..

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate the data and do a cumulative sum of the revenue.  This looks like:

```
select shop_no, customer,
       sum(contribution) as contribution,
       sum(sum(contribution)) over (partition by shop_no order by sum(contribution) desc) as running_contribution
from t
group by shop_no, customer;
```

Next, you want the number of customers where 70% is exceeded.  One method is:

```
select shop_no, count(*) as num_customers
from (select shop_no, customer,
             sum(contribution) as contribution,
             sum(sum(contribution)) over (partition by shop_no order by sum(contribution) desc) as running_contribution
      from t
      group by shop_no, customer
     ) sc
where running_contribution - contribution < 0.7
group by shop_no;
```

The `WHERE` clause is checking that the *previous* value is less than 0.7 -- meaning that it gets the first row that passes the threshold.

Comment: So, my table is huge and the cumulative sum part of the code gets stuck.. Is there a more optimised way to do this? I tried breaking it into 2 steps that is aggregating the data in one step which is done..but getting the running contribution which was the 2nd step got stuck again.

Comment: @alisha . . . This would be the most efficient way to do this.  One issue might be if you have some shops that have zillions of rows due to an anomaly in the data.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `CTE`. (Available in Mysql v8).

**SQL:**

```
WITH recursive 
cte1 AS 
(SELECT *, rank() OVER (partition BY shop_no ORDER BY cust_tot_perc DESC) AS rnk 
  FROM (SELECT customer,shop_no,sum(perc_cust_rev) AS cust_tot_perc 
            FROM abc GROUP BY shop_no,customer) t), 
cte2 AS ( 
  SELECT * FROM   cte1 WHERE  rnk = 1 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT cte1.customer,cte1.shop_no, cte1.cust_tot_perc + cte2.cust_tot_perc, 
  cte2.rnk + 1 FROM cte1 
  INNER JOIN cte2 ON cte1.shop_no = cte2.shop_no AND cte1.rnk = cte2.rnk + 1 
  WHERE      cte2.cust_tot_perc < 0.7 ) 
SELECT   shop_no, max(rnk) FROM     cte2
```

**Explanation:**

- In `cte1` rank customers based on their total perc contribution to the revenue.
- In `cte2` first choose the records with `rnk` 1. Then recursively choose the next `rnk` record for the shop if accumulated % is < 0.7.

---

**DB Fiddle Link:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8ANXmAeka12LzjxYurDn2x/0

Comment: Will this solution work with hive as well?

Comment: @alisha, I don't think so. Looks like Hive does not support recursive CTE. Gordon's answer is neat and should suit your needs better.